# How to override method in uber jar?

Tags: scala, cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-java

I am trying to use this code with Google Cloud Datastore:

```
Query<Entity> query = Query.entityQueryBuilder()
    .kind("Task")
    .filter(PropertyFilter.hasAncestor(
        datastore.newKeyFactory().kind("TaskList").newKey("default")))
    .build();
datastore.run(query, ReadOption.eventualConsistency());
```

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class
>   com.google.datastore.v1.ReadOptions$Builder overrides final method
>   mergeUnknownFields.(Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;)Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder;
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   com.google.datastore.v1.ReadOptions.toBuilder(ReadOptions.java:392)
>     at
>   com.google.datastore.v1.ReadOptions.newBuilder(ReadOptions.java:386)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.toReadOptionsPb(DatastoreImpl.java:217)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:78)

Some general details:

- Language: scala
- Run on: Google compute engine
- Using com.google.guava:guava:19.0 and com.google.cloud:google-cloud:0.3.0 dependencies
- This is the code from google.datastore.v1.protos

  public final Builder mergeUnknownFields(
          final com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet unknownFields) {
        return this;
      }
- this is the code from com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage

  ```
      public BuilderType mergeUnknownFields(UnknownFieldSet unknownFields) {
      this.unknownFields = UnknownFieldSet.newBuilder(this.unknownFields).mergeFrom(unknownFields).build();
      this.onChanged();
      return this;
  }
  ```

`

Answer (score 1):

Adding Shaded Dependencies solved the spark/google cloud client api conflict problem by using:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.google</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a symptom of the issues described in [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1239).

Comment: Yes I also believe this issue is causal by versions mismatch of the ptotobuf protocol in my case between spark and Google cloud  Client api (the same proc run on the same cluster with without spark. Unfortunatly,  using Google cloud dataproc service (for parallel processsing) the spark  classes are preloaded from the service image.